# Hello im trying to publish a build from github to netifly but it wont deploy and i get this error message

Tags: github, svelte, netlify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEr0i.png)8:50:10 PM: ❯ Version
8:50:10 PM:   @netlify/build 26.1.7
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: ❯ Flags
8:50:10 PM:   baseRelDir: true
8:50:10 PM:   buildId: 61f2f7617f65132ba9323b87
8:50:10 PM:   deployId: 61f2f7617f65132ba9323b89
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: ❯ Current directory
8:50:10 PM:   /opt/build/repo
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: ❯ Config file
8:50:10 PM:   /opt/build/repo/netlify.toml
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: ❯ Context
8:50:10 PM:   production
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:50:10 PM:   1. build.command from netlify.toml
8:50:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:50:10 PM: ​
8:50:10 PM: $ npm run build
8:50:10 PM: > moviedb@0.0.1 build
8:50:10 PM: > svelte-kit build
8:50:11 PM: vite v2.7.13 building for production...
8:50:11 PM: transforming...
8:50:11 PM: ✓ 5 modules transformed.
8:50:11 PM: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/MovieDB/moviedb/src/components/MovieCard.svelte" from "src/routes/search/[id].svelte".
8:50:11 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
8:50:11 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
8:50:11 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`
8:50:11 PM: > [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/MovieDB/moviedb/src/components/MovieCard.svelte" from "src/routes/search/[id].svelte".
8:50:11 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
8:50:11 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
8:50:11 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`
8:50:11 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
8:50:11 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
8:50:11 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`
8:50:11 PM:     at onRollupWarning (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:37915:19)
8:50:11 PM:     at onwarn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:37693:13)
8:50:11 PM:     at Object.onwarn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:23153:13)
8:50:11 PM:     at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22431:26)
8:50:11 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22392:26
8:50:11 PM: [!] Error: unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/routes/about.svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/routes/movie/[id].svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/svelte/index.mjs"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/.svelte-kit/runtime/chunks/utils.js"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/svelte/store/index.mjs"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/.svelte-kit/runtime/client/singletons.js"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/.svelte-kit/runtime/paths.js"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/.svelte-kit/generated/manifest.js"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/global.css?used"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/components/Nav.svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/components/PopularMovies.svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:load-fallback) load "/opt/build/repo/src/components/SearchMovies.svelte"
8:50:11 PM: (vite:css) transform "/opt/build/repo/src/routes/search/[id].svelte?svelte&type=style&lang.css"
8:50:11 PM: ​
8:50:11 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:50:11 PM:   "build.command" failed
8:50:11 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:50:11 PM: ​
8:50:11 PM:   Error message
8:50:11 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
8:50:11 PM: ​
8:50:11 PM:   Error location
8:50:11 PM:   In build.command from netlify.toml:
8:50:11 PM:   npm run build
8:50:11 PM: ​
8:50:11 PM:   Resolved config
8:50:11 PM:   build:
8:50:11 PM:     command: npm run build
8:50:11 PM:     commandOrigin: config
8:50:11 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
8:50:11 PM:     publishOrigin: config
8:50:11 PM:   functionsDirectory: /opt/build/repo/functions
8:50:12 PM: Caching artifacts
8:50:12 PM: Started saving node modules
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving node modules
8:50:12 PM: Started saving build plugins
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving build plugins
8:50:12 PM: Started saving pip cache
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving pip cache
8:50:12 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
8:50:12 PM: Started saving go dependencies
8:50:12 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
8:50:14 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
8:50:14 PM: Creating deploy upload records
8:50:14 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:50:14 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
8:50:14 PM: Finished processing build request in 18.742636927s
Docs
Pricing
Support
News
Terms
© 2022 Netlify

Comment: What do the relevant files from this error message look like? `Rollup failed to resolve import "/MovieDB/moviedb/src/components/MovieCard.svelte" from "src/routes/search/[id].svelte". `

Comment: Hello i have added to codeing of bothe files in aimg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your project is in your root directory, I don't think that `/MovieDB/moviedb/src/components/MovieCard.svelte` is the right path to access that file.

Try using a relative path from `[id].svelte` to access `MovieCard.svelte`. I would try `import MovieCard from ../../../components/MovieCard.svelte`

Comment: The path did  not woklr but you where right! I changed it to ../../../components/MovieCard.svelte now its live thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it!